# Can I change github repo name from uppercase to lowercase without losing link target?

Tags: github, rename, repository

As title says, is it possible to rename a github repo like `fooBar-for-MySQL-and-PHP` to `foobar-for-mysql-and-php` without killing the link to your repo ? And have there been any issues with common git tools ?

To make this clearer: This question is not about renaming and losing watchers, starrers and forks, it's about changing from uppercase to lowercase, which might have effects like "URL not found". I have too much starrers & forks to simply try this out.

Github's official help section does not note this case (https://help.github.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the repo page, it is no problem

```
http://github.com/svnpenn/BM
```

However for the "Github Pages" page, big problem

```
http://svnpenn.github.io/BM
```

```
404
There isn't a GitHub Page here.
Are you trying to publish one? We'll send you an email when your page has been 
built. It may take up to ten minutes until your page is available.
```

To conclude, do not do it.

Comment: Thanks. Crap. My username has caps in it. So I can't make a page?

Comment: @Kenzo I'm having the same issue, it seems like the only way around it is to change the user name

Comment: And it's such a simple server directive to enforce lower case.

Comment: It worked for me. Apparently GiHub has fixed the issue and there may be capital letters in both usernames and repository names.